# Bash Cut text from line with different delimiters

Tags: bash, delimiter, cut

I have a variable with value like:

```
@capability_ids type="list">[LOADBALANCER]</capability_ids>@
```

And need to extract from this string type of equipment ( LOADBALANCER ).

I've tried to use cut, but don't know how write cut command with different delimiters.

```
DeviceType=$( echo $DeviceTypeDirty | cut -d'[' -f1)
```

Can enywone help me with right solution on bash?

Comment: Why is your string in a variable and not in an array? how did you obtain the data? Is it obtained from a file or an external process? Do you need the full data, or do you only need the values you showed?

Comment: Ok, I've edited a question to simplify it. Only data within square brackets - LOADBALANCER

Comment: My other questions remain: how did you obtain the data? is it obtained from a file or an external process, and do you need the full data or only the field you showed?

Comment: This data obtained from external system, using ssh requests, and I need only field.

Comment: And how are you going to use the fields? do you need to process them one by one, or do you want them all in an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `awk` with regular expression: `awk -F '[\\[\\]]' '{print $2}'`

```
$ echo '@capability_ids type="list">[L3SWITCH]/capability_ids>@'|awk -F '[\\[\\]]' '{print $2}'
$ L3SWITCH
```

---

```
$ DeviceType=$( echo "$DeviceTypeDirty" | awk -F '[\\[\\]]' '{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried and got to extract "LOADBALANCER"

```
Administrators-MacBook-Pro:~$ echo "\"list\">[LOADBALANCER]   
</capability_ids>@"|awk -F '[][]' '{print $2}'
LOADBALANCER
Administrators-MacBook-Pro:~$
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for copying BigDataLearner's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `cut`:

```
DeviceTypeDirty="@capability_ids type="list">[LOADBALANCER]</capability_ids>@"
DeviceType="$(echo "$DeviceTypeDirty" | cut -d'[' -f2 | cut -d']' -f1)"
```

Output:

```
echo "$DeviceType"
LOADBALANCER
```